# Convert XML Document to Json without quotes in nodes with decimal values C#

Tags: c#, json, xml, type-conversion

I have an XML Document Doc :

```
<root>
 <decimal>12.55</decimal>
 <string>Test</string>
</root>
```

I want to convert this Document into json without quotes for the decimal node

So if I use the JsonConverter

```
JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(Doc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, true)
```

the result is:

```
{
"decimal": "12.55",
"string": "Test"
}
```

but I want the following result:

```
{
"decimal": 12.55,
"string": "Test"
}
```

How can I set the type "decimal" in the node

```
 <decimal>12.55</decimal>
```

That the JsonConverter detect it as a decimal value and convert it into json without quotes.

I tried to set an attribute or type or namespace in the XML node but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

A compiller doesn't now what type do you want. So the simpliest way would be to parse json

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var json =  JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xDoc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, true);

var jObj=JObject.Parse(json);

jObj["decimal"]=Convert.ToDecimal(jObj["decimal"]);

json = jObj.ToString();
```

json

```
{
  "decimal": 12.55,
  "string": "Test"
}
```

another way would be to create a class and deserialize instead of parsing

```
json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json));

public class Root
{
    public decimal @decimal { get; set; }
    public string @string { get; set; }
}
```